# how to create dynamic dataframe name in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

how to create dynamic dataframe name in pyspark
here I am not able to create new dataframe using below code it will give me only last dataframe name, I need All dataframe name

```
for prime2 in pdf2:
    ol2 =  Bucket_path + prime2['S3_File_with_Path']
    t = 1
    sd = {}  
    testR = "df" + str(t)
    print("testR",testR)
    sd[testR] = spark.read.format("parquet").load(ol2).cache() 
    t = t + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're creating dict inside the loop, so getting a dict with only one (last) entry. Try changing code to something like this:

```
sd = {}  
for prime2 in pdf2:
    ol2 =  Bucket_path + prime2['S3_File_with_Path']
    t = 1
    testR = "df" + str(t)
    print("testR",testR)
    df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(ol2).cache() 
    sd[testR] = df
    t = t + 1 

# sd dict is available here, all the dataframes are inside
print(len(sd))
```

Comment: hey @Ajinkya, was that answer helpful?